# mintty does not find my theme directory

Tags: terminal, cygwin, theme

If I understand the tty manpage correctly, theme files are by default looked up in a subdirectory named `themes` under the config directory, and in the absence of a --config option, one default location for the config directory is `~/.mintty/config`.

I have created a directory `~/.mintty/config/themes` and placed some theme files into it. Then I started mintty. In the mintty configuration (Options/Looks) is a selector for themes, but it just says "No Themes", and none of the files in my themes directory are shown.

What could be the reason?

I'm using mintty 2.7.6 on Cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put them in `~/.mintty/themes`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, I just find out another possibility. First, I put it into `~/.config/mintty/themes` (I guess `~/.mintty/themes` would have worked too), but this was not enough: I had to rename the theme files. I first had named them according to the pattern `.mintty.NAME`, and this was not found; but after renaming them to `NAME.theme`, they are found now. Don't know why ...... So: Wrong directory AND wrong naming schema.